# Why are columns in Azure Table Storage retrieved as "keys" in my function?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

```
[FunctionName("GetInfo")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        [Table("table", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] TableClient tableClient,
        ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            var data = new List<object>();

            var entities = tableClient.Query<Azure.Data.Tables.TableEntity>().ToList();

            foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                var info = new
                {
                    id = entity.RowKey,
                    name = entity.title,
                    createdOn = entity.Timestamp
                };

                data.Add(info);
            }
```

So I have this function that I am running locally right now and using postman to test the call. The entries in the table has some columns, like isDeleted, createdOn, createdBy, description, etc.

I put the `entities` on a watch and it shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np1CG.png)

All the columns in the table, like isDeleted, is part of "keys" which is a level below where I want them to be, plus, they only have the key, not the value, aka who actually created, when actually created, is it deleted or not.

I think in this case, I can't even filter the query to only retrieve non soft deleted entries, also, `name = entity.title` also doesnt work because it would have to be `entity.keys.title` except that doesnt have a value neither is it accessible.

How do I go about querying these items?

Answer (score 0):

I have figure it out. I needed to create a custom table entity to suit my needs.

```
public class MyEntity : Azure.Data.Tables.ITableEntity
{
}
```

fill this up with all the column headers of my table, and using these properties is as simple as

```
var entities = tableClient
                .Query<MyEntity>()
                .Where(entity => entity.isDeleted == false)
                .ToList();
```